# Animate SVG images

Tags: html, animation, svg

Can I animate an SVG circle?

```
<svg>
    <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
    <animate 
        xlink:href="#orange-circle"
        attributeName="cx"
        from="50"
        to="450" 
        dur="1s"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

Similarly, I am trying to animate an image:

```
<svg>
    <image id="orange-circle" x="0" y="20" width="200" height="180"  xlink:href="cat.png" /> 
    <animate 
        xlink:href="#orange-circle"
        attributeName="cx"
        from="50"
        to="450" 
        dur="1s"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

How can I make the above code work?

Comment: What seems to be the actual problem? Aren't the animations starting? What exactly is wron with them? Is there any surrounding code that might play a role?

Comment: Look a FAQ animate: https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example code (easy) with image is beautiful:**

```html
<svg>
  <circle fill="blue" cx="150" cy="100" r="50"></circle>
  <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/ANS7Rkc.png" x="-50" y="72" width="100" height="50">
    <animate attributeName="x" from="-50" to="300" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </image>
</svg>
```

Example (no image)
https://codepen.io/danjiro/post/how-to-make-svg-loop-animation

**Tutorial:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial

enjoin us ;)